# mongo replica set unable to import the example restaurant json

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo and I have just set up a replicaset localy on my laptop.

I'm trying to import the demo database of restaurants from here :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/dataset.json

and executed the mongoimport comand as this:

```
mongoimport -v --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file dataset.json
```

End the import just stops at 45%

```
2015-12-29T12:42:56.847-0500    filesize: 11880944 bytes
2015-12-29T12:42:56.847-0500    using fields:
2015-12-29T12:42:56.859-0500    connected to: localhost
2015-12-29T12:42:56.859-0500    ns: test.restaurants
2015-12-29T12:42:56.860-0500    connected to node type: replset
2015-12-29T12:42:56.860-0500    using write concern: w='majority', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2015-12-29T12:42:56.861-0500    dropping: test.restaurants
2015-12-29T12:42:56.864-0500    using write concern: w='majority', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2015-12-29T12:42:59.859-0500    [#########...............] test.restaurants     4.5 MB/11.3 MB (39.9%)
2015-12-29T12:43:02.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:05.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:08.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:11.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:14.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:17.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:20.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:23.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:26.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:29.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:32.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:35.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:38.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:41.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:44.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:47.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:50.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:53.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:56.850-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:43:59.849-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:44:02.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:44:05.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:44:08.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:44:11.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
2015-12-29T12:44:14.848-0500    [##########..............] test.restaurants     5.2 MB/11.3 MB (45.5%)
```

On the slave there is a database test created but if I try to do a find:
db.restaurants.find();

I get back :

```
Error: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }
```

This is my replica config from master:

```
    repl1:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
        "_id" : "repl1",
        "version" : 7,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "mongo1:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : 0,
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "mongo2:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : 0,
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "mongo3:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : 0,
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                }
        }
}
```

Looks like that the slaves do not recognize that they are part of replica set.

Where can i find some more info what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

> End the import just stops at 45%

It's probably fine and just building indexes. Or you could be running out of some system resource, or it could just be slow. Tail the logs for that `mongod` process for more information. Check your disk for free space, and check `top` or whatever system monitoring tools you have to see what resources are being used while the import appears to be stopped at 45%.

> On the slave there is a database test created but if I try to do a
>   find: db.restaurants.find();
>
> I get back :
>
> ```
> Error: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }
> ```

You can't query data on a secondary without first telling your driver or the mongo shell that it's okay to do so. Run `rs.slaveOk()` first and then you can run your `find()` query.

Comment: tnx for the hints, at the end I found out it was a firewall issue, the master was able to talk to all slaves but the slaves were not able to reply, it was a firewalld blocking the slaves on master

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall that was blocking the slaves to communicate back to the master. The master was able to communicate to the slaves but the slaves were not able to answer back.

If you have some similar issue check your firewalld if you are using Centos7

Answer (score 0):

To import you can try this code:

```
mongoimport --db <database-name> --collection <collection-name> --file ~/path/file-name.json
```